# Using Meteor 1.4 Beta

Tags: meteor, beta

I'm trying to use the meteor 1.4 beta and wanted advice on the best way to get set-up - I've never used a software beta before and am a bit unsure.

1. Do I just download the latest file from github? In this case https://github.com/meteor/meteor/releases/tag/release%2FMETEOR%401.4-beta.7
2. How do I configure the file on my system such that I can use the meteor command in my terminal as normal?
3. Are there any other things I need to set up or be aware of to use this version?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new project using the recommended (current) Meteor version :

```
meteor create test
```

Then upgrade the newly created project to the latest beta available :

```
cd test
meteor update --release 1.4-beta.7
```

There you go, the `test` project is on the latest beta and outside of it you can still use your system-wide Meteor install.

Regarding 1.4 specifically :
The latest dev bundle comes with MongoDB 3.2, if you're upgrading an existing project it will warn you about the need to migrate your database, the easiest way to do so in dev is simply to run `meteor reset`.
Also, `meteor node` still points to `v0.10.45` but your app will run with `v4.4.7` (just `console.log(process.version)`).